# What is the enum value for SND_SYSTEM as defined for winmm.dll PlaySound?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a need to play a wav file as a 'System Sound' in Windows 7. I have found various information on the internet that points at using winmm.dll via p/invoke to play the sound, with the SND_SYSTEM flag set.

Every example I find, omits the definition for SND_SYSTEM in their PlaySoundFlags enumeration. I have looked at various copies of mmsystem.h availiable online and none of them seem to declare it either.

If you can, please give a *complete* enum of the SND_ flags, including SND_SYSTEM. Failing that, a link to a windows 7 version of the mmsystem.h header file would be useful.

Environment is Visual C# 2017.

Comment: Visual Studio's C++ support and "Go to definition" tell me these happen to be defined (in this version of the Windows SDK) in `playsoundapi.h`. I encourage you to install the Windows SDK (and C++ support) yourself so you can answer such questions yourself. Another useful technique is to search for `#define SND_SYSTEM`, as this will often give you a copy (or equivalent) of the header containing the `#define`, but nothing beats the authoritative source.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that, have never touched C++.. went straight from VB6 to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the windows platform SDK you can get the required header files.

In the windows 10 platform SDK the values are defined in playsoundapi.h (referenced from mmsystem.h)

```
#define SND_SYNC            0x0000  /* play synchronously (default) */
#define SND_ASYNC           0x0001  /* play asynchronously */
#define SND_NODEFAULT       0x0002  /* silence (!default) if sound not found */
#define SND_MEMORY          0x0004  /* pszSound points to a memory file */
#define SND_LOOP            0x0008  /* loop the sound until next sndPlaySound */
#define SND_NOSTOP          0x0010  /* don't stop any currently playing sound */

#define SND_NOWAIT      0x00002000L /* don't wait if the driver is busy */
#define SND_ALIAS       0x00010000L /* name is a registry alias */
#define SND_ALIAS_ID    0x00110000L /* alias is a predefined ID */
#define SND_FILENAME    0x00020000L /* name is file name */
#define SND_RESOURCE    0x00040004L /* name is resource name or atom */

#if (WINVER >= 0x0400)
#define SND_PURGE           0x0040  /* purge non-static events for task */
#define SND_APPLICATION     0x0080  /* look for application specific association */
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */
#define SND_SENTRY      0x00080000L /* Generate a SoundSentry event with this sound */
#define SND_RING        0x00100000L /* Treat this as a "ring" from a communications app - don't duck me */
#define SND_SYSTEM      0x00200000L /* Treat this as a system sound */
```